# Multiply large numbers in c

Tags: c++, c

I have two integer x and y
Let us say x= 10^5 and y = 10^8
Now I have to multiply the numbers and store them in a variable z. I need not have the exact value. z can have the answer modulo 100000009. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate `z = (x * y) mod 100000009`?

Comment: Depending on how large the numbers are, you could look into the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library.

Answer (score 4):

In general you should be relying on the relationship:

```
(a * b) % n = (a % n) * (b % n) % n
```

In this particular case it doesn't help much because your `a` and `b` are both smaller than `n`, but for larger `a` or `b` this guarantees that the largest multiplication you need to handle is of the order of `n^2` and not `a * b`.

On a 64-bit system your current value of `n^2` would fit inside a `long`.  If you anticipate larger values then you'll need an arbitrary precision math library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    typedef unsigned long long ull;
    ull x = std::pow(10,5);
    ull y = std::pow(10,8);
    ull z = (x*y) % 100000009;
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was think double not long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logarithms and exponents. Exponent is the function f(x)=e^x, where e is a mathmaticall constant equal to 2.71828182845...
Logarithm (marked by ln) is the inverse of the exponent.

Since ln(a*b)=ln(a)+ln(b), a*b=e^(ln(a)+ln(b)).

remark:
the method was wןdely used before the computers.